# Export html to Excel format?

Tags: html, css, scala

I need to export html to Excel format in playscala ?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: It's possible. I recommend http://www.listly.io/. It makes web page to Excel in seconds, and finds the CSSpath for list-like contents.
You can extract and download the contents without a parsing code.